# How do I open a Linux .bin file on a PC?

Tags: windows, bin

Everything I find on this question is about using programming languages like C++ or Python to open/read a .bin file. I have basic C++ knowledge and don't know anything about Python.

I have a .bin on my Windows 10 PC from a Linux computer. I want to use my PC to see the contents of that .bin file so I can understand what it does when used n the Linux computer.

When I open the .bin file I get a lot of weird NULL characters, obviously because the file is in 1s and 0s. I need to see the contents of the .bin file in a way that is human readable.

Comment: [Take The Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53896712/edit) your question to explain how did you get that binary file

Comment: Without more details, your question is unclear. What does "opening a Linux `.bin` file" means to you (on Windows).

Comment: You seem to be confused about a number of things. Let me just clarify one of them: If you see a NULL character, then you are probably opening the file using a hex editor or a plain-text editor and you have found the ASCII NULL character, which consists of eight zeros in a row (starting at an offset that is a multiple of 8). If a file consists of the bits 1010101010..., you'd see no NULL characters.

Answer (score 2):

> How do I open a Linux .bin file on a [Windows] PC?

#### You don't open it.

You might examine that file in some binary editor (e.g. some hexadecimal one).

But you could install a [Linux distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_distribution) on your PC (then run that Linux executable on your Linux system).

You should find out what kind of file it is in some other way. Perhaps the person who provided you that file knows more about it. The `.bin` suffix don't tell much.

If that file is a binary [executable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable), it probably won't have any `.bin` suffix (at least, the convention on Linux is to not have any file path extension on them). Of course executables have an [operating-system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system) specific format so can be run only on the OS they are targetting. On Linux systems, executables usually have [ELF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) format (so their first four bytes are ["magic numbers"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)): `0x7F 'E' 'L' 'F'`) and often are [dynamically linked](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_linker) (so you need some [shared library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Library_(computing)#Shared_libraries), perhaps some `libc.so`, e.g. the [GNU C library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_C_Library), to run them). On Windows, executables usually have the [PE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable) format (and depend on some [DLL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic-link_library)s).

If that file is some binary data, you need to learn (otherwise) what [file format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_format) it is following.

If you wanted to *run* a Linux executable on Windows, that is a very different question. Perhaps you could try using [WSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux) (or you could install some [Linux distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_distribution) on your computer). However, in general, you should not trust running any random executable (from a source you don't trust) on your computer. Beware of [malware](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malware).

Traditionally, most Linux software are [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software). If your file comes from a free software, you might consider getting its source code and [port](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Porting) it to Windows (so build it on your Windows machine). Sometimes it is very easy (e.g. when the software is using a cross-system framework like [Qt](https://qt.io/), [POCO](https://pocoproject.org/), [GTK](https://gtk.org/), etc..). Sometimes, it could take years of work (if the source code is huge and Linux specific).

If you want to [statically analyze](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_program_analysis) some (perhaps suspicious) Linux ELF executable, it is much simpler to do that on Linux (using tools like [readelf(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/readelf.1.html), [objdump(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/objdump.1.html) etc...)

> I need to see the contents of the .bin file in a way that is human readable.

Even on Linux, that is generally not possible. It might be called [decompilation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decompiler) ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53894009/841108) answer is explaining a bit more why it is not really possible). And even if you get some binary executable for Windows, you won't succeed in decompiling it entirely: there is some significant loss of information (and of knowledge) between the [source code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_code) and the executable obtained by [compiling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler) that source code.

To learn more about operating systems, read [*Operating Systems: Three Easy Pieces*](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/) (freely downloadable).

Comment: I believe it's an executable file, not quite sure. When I transfer the files from the Linux server to windows the file's type is just "File". Even in the properties the file type just says File. I assumed it was a bin file because I used WinSCP to transfer the file from a bin folder on the Linux server to my PC.

Comment: Then you cannot do anything useful with it (unless you have a Linux distribution or at least WSL) on Windows.